# logical Operators in objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Logical Operators in objective c language?

Comment: What would you like to know about them? Can you make your question more specific?

Comment: How to use logical operators in objective c?

Answer (score 14):

Random stab in the dark at what you're asking:

yes, Objective-C has logical operators. They are exactly the same as in C

`&&` is and
`||` is or
`!` is not

so an expression `!a || b` can be read as "(not a) or b"